# colorbox in WordPress partially working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, colorbox

I am trying to use Jack Moore's Colorbox on a WordPress page. The Colorbox is being used to call a custom PHP page using the iframe option. The overlay appears and I can also see that the page is loading based on the browser status bar, but the page doesn't display. It's like the Colorbox box isn't being created?

I've searched and tried everything I can think of.

Link HTML on http://tammylavertyhomes.com/listings/

```
<a class="rlpo_button rlpo_button-5 single" href="http://www.royallepageottawa.ca/agents/details-m.php?mls=840202&amp;ret=RES">View More</a>
```

In the footer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
jQuery('.single').colorbox({iframe:true, width:540, height:750});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem, that is, because colorbox doesn't display the div after loading.

You can fix(patch) this with that code :

```
jQuery('.single').colorbox({
  iframe:true, 
  width:540, 
  height:750,
  onComplete: function(){
    jQuery('#colorbox').show();
  }
});
```